# Prisma - How to query by relation? (Get posts of followed users)

Tags: javascript, node.js, orm, graphql, prisma

I'm building a simple feed where the user can see all the posts of the people he follows.

So in theory what I want to do is to get all posts (findMany) where the author of the posts is followed by the user who is requesting.

Sounds simple but I cannot find anything in the docs that explain how to do it.

Here is my schema:

**User:**

```
model User {
  uid String @id @default(uuid())
  username String? @db.VarChar(24) @unique 
  followers Follows[] @relation(name: "follower")
  following Follows[] @relation(name: "following")
}
```

**Post:**

```
model Post {
  id             Int     @id @default(autoincrement())
  name           String  @db.VarChar(255) 
  author         User @relation(fields: [authorId], references: [uid])
  authorId String
```

**Follows** (Explicit Many-To-Many)

```
model Follows { 
  follower      User  @relation(name: "follower", fields: [followerId], references: [uid])
  followerId    String 
  following     User @relation(name: "following", fields: [followingId], references: [uid])
  followingId   String
```

Here is how I imagined it to work:

```
return prisma.post.findMany({   
        where: {
          author: {
            some: {
              followers: { 
                followerId: {
                  equals: args.userId
                 } 
              }
            }
          }
        },
        include: {
          author: {   
            include: {
              followers: {
                include: {
                  follower: true
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      })
```

The error I'm getting:

```
Unknown arg `some` in where.author.some
```

I also tried it without the "some" but then I'm getting the following output:

```
Unknown arg `followers` in where.author.followers
```